# What does .flashing do in Play!2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Can someone explain what the Flash Scope is? What does .flashing() do and how to use both of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roughly flashing is useful in the cases you need a temporary parameter. Common case is a message to be displayed to the next page accessed using a redirect

This is very useful when you need information part of a workflow but which you don't want them to be part of the contract declared by a template (parameters).

A flashed information is stored in the cookie **not** hashed (in clear thus) and its lifetime is scoped to the very next request -- discarded after.

The way to use flashing is simply use flashing which a sequence of strings kvp, like so
     Redirect(routes.Application.login()).flashing("error", "You must be logged in")

Where login is using a template to be rendered which contains
     @flash.get("error") map { x =>
           @x
      }

Answer (score 0):

Flash is typically used with redirect but its not tied to that. Essentially the Flash scope works exactly like the Session, but with two differences:

- data are kept for only one request
- the Flash cookie is not signed,
  making it possible for the user to modify it.

POST/Redirect/GET is the main reason to start using flashing.